# Should a Mezuzah be placed in the foundations of a new house?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

Should a Mezuzah be placed in the foundations of a new house?

If yes, where? N.A.

If no, why not? A few contributors have explained that the mitzvah of the mezuzah is accomplished by respecting the correct position on the door post.

[image: Hanochas Even Hapinah]My question is originated by reading about the archeological findings of written material. Some Jewish tradition call for a ritual congregation at the site of a new house. In this instance, some traditions call for a wishful text (written by a kosher sofer) in a bottle to be buried in the foundations

Comment: Why do you think a mezuzah should be placed in the foundations of a house? Last time I checked you needed to put mezuzot on the *doorposts* of a home.

Comment: A, Allegretti, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Could you possibly [edit] you question to include some information about why you suspect that placing a mezuza in the foundations of a new house may be mandated? That would make the question a great deal more compelling and could lead to more satisfying answers.

Comment: Archaeological digs in the Middle East, going all the way back to the days and cities of the kingdoms of Sumer and Akkad, have found documents deposited in the foundations of temples, palaces, and other "royal" buildings. A LOT of information about kings and their accomplishments(doing a good job of tooting their own horns, of course)has been recovered from such foundation deposits.  The question, IMO, is a valid one, except that the Jewish version of such deposits weren't mezuzahs, but probably had other names/rules associated with them.A copper deposit of a 1/2shekel was dug up not long ago.

Comment: The foundation hoard is in a book I bought in the Israel Museum.  It says the hoard of 139 prutot was deposited in a wall in an oil lamp by the owner shortly before the First Revolt in a house in En Gedi, probably "in order to improve the good fortune of his household."(the book's description) The official rate of exchange at that time was 128 Prutot to a half shekel, plus the 8 percent fee when exchanging metals, bringing the total to an exact half shekel amount required once in a lifetime by the Torah, but yearly in Second Temple times.

Comment: Interesting point about the article, but I've personally never heard of that practice (although to be fair, that doesn't mean much). Do you have a link to the complete article where you read about this practice? Or a source for that picture (it's hard to know with crtainty what they're doing baed on the picture alone)?

Comment: Is [this article](http://www.kolhazman.co.il/272499) the source of your picture? If so, please [edit] to credit and explain the context. Even better, given that we probably don't have license to re-publish the picture, include a link to the article and a summary of the relevant information from there.

Answer (score 6):

No. the Torah says the Mezuza belongs on the doorpost.

A Mezuza belongs on the doorposts - on the top third of the right-hand-side when walking in - and only once the house is ready to be lived in.

Putting a Kosher Mezuza in the foundations would be problematic since a Mezuza has holiness and **burying it in the foundations is not a respectable place for it**.

Comment: What's wrong with burying it in the foundations? We bury mezuzot all the time. It's generally considered a respectable method of disposal

Comment: @DoubleAA - when the last time you heard of somebody burying a Kosher Mezuza? (I specifically wrote "Kosher" in my answer, since a non-Kosher Mezuza isn't a Mezuza and burying it is the way to go.)  I understood from the OP that a Kosher Mezuza would be buried in the foundation as some sort of segula.

Answer (score 2):

The metaphysical benefits of a mitzvah, can only be attained when the mitzvah is performed correctly.

In Jewish law, the place for the mezuzah to be placed, is on the doorposts of our dwellings, not embedded in a building foundation.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. By Mitzvot we say מחשבה טובה מצרפה למעשה so you can get all the benefits by just trying sincerely

Comment: Sorry, but you're operating with a flawed understanding of the quote. See it in context (Kiddushin 40a), where it's clear that it's referring to a person who attempted to do a [REAL] mitzvah (not an imaginary one), and for reasons beyond his control, he was prevented from performing the mitzvah. "מחשבה טובה מצרפה למעשה, שנאמר: אז נדברו יראי ה' איש אל רעהו ויקשב ה' וישמע ויכתב ספר זכרון לפניו ליראי ה' ולחושבי שמו, מאי ולחושבי שמו? אמר רב אסי: אפילו חשב אדם לעשות מצוה, ונאנס ולא עשאה, מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו עשאה.

Comment: Your context doesn't contribute anything. He is trying to fulfill the REAL Mitzva of Mezuza, and due to not knowing enough about it, he was unable to perform it.

Comment: Rabbi Chaim of Volozhin disagrees with you. See "Nefesh HaChaim" (Perakim, 4) והגע עצמך, כגון אם יטריד אדם עצמו לילה הראשונה של פסח בכונת אכילת כזית מצה, שתהא האכילה בקדושה וטהרה ודביקות, וימשיך ההכנה כל הלילה עד שיומשך זמן האכילה עד לאחר שעלה השחר או לאחר נץ החמה, הרי כל טהרת מחשבתו פיגול הוא לא ירצה. ומי שאכל הכזית מצה בזמנה אף בלא קדושה וטהרה יתירה, הרי קיים מצות עשה הכתובה בתורה ותבא עליו ברכה.

Comment: No he doesn't. He's discussing someone who never gets passed preparations. Our case is someone who did his intended action, it just so happens some legal requirement was missing. Like wearing Tefillin that unknowingly are invalid.

Comment: Sorry. Read the Nefesh HaChaim again. He is doing a study in contrast of two people who BOTH ate matza. One is someone who simply performed the mitzvah in its proper time. The other one is someone who erroneously ate the matza too late, because he thought it was more important to Hashem that he perform the mitzva with greater spiritual preparations, despite missing the prescribed halachic time spot.

Comment: He thought eating in the wrong time would be better than eating without preparation. He didn't think eating after dawn was the right time. That exactly the point. Averah Lishmah is not מחשבה טובה

Comment: This man did not intend to do any עבירה לשמה. Due to his erroneous מחשבה טובה perceptions, on the bottom line, he passively neglected to perform a מצות עשה in the prescribed manner. This type of behavior is castigated by R' Chaim of Volozhin as פיגול הוא לא ירצה.

Answer (score 2):

Halacha mandates that the mezuzah is to go on the doorposts of one's home, as it specifically requires in the Torah ([Deut. 6:9](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9970/jewish/Chapter-6.htm#v=9); ibid. [11:20](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9975/jewish/Chapter-11.htm#v=20)). There is no mitzvah to put a mezuzah in the foundation.